# Drive Route Automation that is NOT shortest distance

Tags: routing, vehicle-routing-problem

I work on a wireless engineering team and we are getting ready to test some antenna propagations for our network. This involves setting up the antenna in a certain location and then driving around the area surrounding the antenna to collect data on our settings, power level, etc.

I was thinking that I could perhaps buffer the point we want to setup the antenna and then develop a drive route that will go through all the roads in that area or some other means to ensure that the driver can hit all roads without having to double back as much but all the drive routing tools I've seen try to get you from point A to point B in the shortest distance possible when in my case I guess I would want the longest route possible within a given area.

Are there drive routing automation tools (in Arc or something else) that will give me a route that is not the shortest route but will go through as many roads as possible from a given location within a given range?

Comment: Sounds somehow similar to Travelling salesman problem (TSP), see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem - define a set of points all over the route you want to cover and then you can use an algorithm for TSP. There is a GRASS tool for it, so if you have GRASS or QGIS, you could use this: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/v.net.salesman.html - See also GIS SE topics on TSP: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travelling-salesman

Comment: I’d look into garbage collection route planning which also needs to optimize how to visit all parts of a connected set of streets.